# while loading the content of the html using ajax to the same page , only content is loaded but javascript actions are not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, web-development-server

When we start accessing another HTML document using AJAX only content of the HTML is loaded but it doesn't work javascript code in that particular code. How do we overcome this

even alert box couldn't open

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest; 

 xhr.open('GET','alert.html',true);

xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

var text = xhr.responseText;
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = text;

xhr.send();
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: From your explanation and your code it looks like you are getting only a portion of the html document, whatever is inside of the id "content". More than likely the javascript code is in a script tag in the body someplace outside of the html within "content" and the javascript is not loading.

Check to see where is the javascript and make sure you load. For example if the javascript is at the bottom of the body tag use

    document.getElementByTagName('body')[0]